# SPGridView Field - javascript:window.open issue

Tags: javascript, gridview, spgridview

I have an issue where in the SPGridView if I add a hyperlink field or anything, it seems like the javascript:window.open does not work.  It does not show as a hyperlink.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this one myself:

```
        BoundField colCaseTitle = new BoundField();
        colCaseTitle.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
        colCaseTitle.DataField = "CaseTitleModal";
        colCaseTitle.HeaderText = "Title";
        colCaseTitle.SortExpression = "CaseTitle";
        **colCaseTitle.HtmlEncode = false;**
        dataFilterList += ",";
        this.spGridView.Columns.Add(colCaseTitle);
```

Also added this to my class that I am binding with:

return "" + CaseTitle + "";